# How do I get my bot to send a message when an unauthorized user presses a button? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So, I'm making a bot, and I'm working with buttons at the moment, and when someone runs a command for example `;buy item` and they press a button, it does stuff yk, but when someone who isn't the message author press the button, the bot also responds, and I don't want this. I want my bot to just send maybe an ephemeral message to the user saying something like, "This button isn't for you" or something. So, my question is, how do I make my bot send a message when a user *who isn't the message author* presses the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that using an if statement in the start of your collector. After you make a `messageComponentCollector()` in your channel, in the top of it, you can add:

```js
collector.on('collect', (click) => {
  if (click.user.id !== message.author.id) {
    return click.reply({
      content: 'This button is not for you!',
      ephemeral: true
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: If the answer solved your question, please accept it as it will show future users that this solution worked for your problem